# SOLVED Createblock definition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

i search around a lot about references of this function. but the documentation have a big lack. does somebody explain me this part of code (deeply) ?

```
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            ClassElementLikeSelect::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
```

i don't understand this solution. i find this everywhere but nobody explain why you set that argument (is_render_to_js_template for example) .

UPDATE:

the createBlock is definite with block Factory and are inside these classes

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only used in a couple of places

https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=is_render_to_js_template&unscoped_q=is_render_to_js_template

```
    /**
     * Block Factory
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $name
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    public function createBlock($type, $name = '', array $arguments = [])
```

So it's arguments that you are passing to block.

As to why.  I'm baffled.  Other than online tutorials and the two references above I can't find anything.

You can echo out blocks.  Sometimes useful for debugging.  See if it makes a difference to output?

```
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Vendor\Extension\Block\Hello')
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: thank you man probably i have found the answer i put under the question. but you help me a lot really thanks